# Does a user's age increase with each year they have been on the site?

Tags: support, users

I am working with the Stack Overflow dataset, and was wondering whether the "Age" property a user sets increases appropriately with time? For example, if I joined 5 years ago and said my age was 20, then my present Age value should be 25 without me having to update it each year.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's based on the date of birth set in the user's profile, so it will update automatically.

For some reason though, the `Age` property does something else instead of flooring it as I'd expect. Either it's rounding it, or as [@MartijnPieters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) suspects, it's subtracting the current year from your year of birth.

For example, try my user ID in [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/209152/272354/age-of-a-user) (2074608). It's supposed to be 15, but the `Age` property is 16.

Comment: I think it's just a `currentyear - year-of-birth` shortcut. So not so much rounded as incorrect for most until their actual birthday has already passed this year.

Comment: E.g. you are shown as 16 prematurely, because your birthday is later in the year. Mine is showing the correct age because my birthday was earlier in the year, but for about 3 months it would have been wrong.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I'm not 100% sure, but I've added it to the answer just in case.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: you can test it in 6 months time. :-P You'll be listed as 17 from the moment the first 2015 datadump is created.

Comment: A nice feature I think, "Age" only reveals year of birth, not the whole DOB.

Comment: [There are good reasons to not make the age field too accurate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/does-your-profile-contain-your-exact-birthday-is-that-safe)